# How do I say "The story has to have a moral"?

Tags: translation, word-requests

Is there any way to say that when you write a story, it has to "have a moral"? (i.e. it has to teach you something). Is there a clear translation for that in Chinese?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can translate 'moral' as `寓意` and thus 'have a moral' as '有寓意' (故事要有寓意). Alternatively, you could say `故事要有教育意义` (the story has to be educational).

Comment: http://www.iciba.com/moral?renovate=349341： 6. N-COUNT 
http://www.nciku.com/search/all/moral：８。 意义，寓意，教训：在一共６０个例句之中有３个涉及需要的义项